# SoundPool need play sound with tempo sync

Tags: android, audio, asynchronous, playback, soundpool

i am developing a game similar to Simon (copycat) but in my case, i want to play de demo game making rhythms, but i can not get my sounds to be played at tempo time, i mean:

- If i schedule the playback for 4 sounds each 300ms, it does asynchronously...
- I am using SoundPool and i have tried to play the sounds from raw and from assets, and differente formats like mp3 and ogg.
- I've tried using Chronometer as timer and also i've tried a second Thread using System.currentTimeMillis() to check the time to play each sample....both cases i've got the same result...async...
- After some playbacks sometimes i get the demo to be played at time...40 percent of success

What i am doing wrong?? 
Thanks in advance